# Mysqldump and gzip multiple tables with where clause not working in PhPMyAdmin

Tags: sql, mysql

I use AMPPS to run Apache and MySQL on a Mac OSX 10.9.2. I tried to mysqldump and gzip table1, table3 and table4 where `id` is greater than 500 through the PhPMyAdmin sql command line. However, after running the below query, MySQL said `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...`:

```sh
mysqldump -u username -p password database1 table1 table3 table4 --where=`id`>=500  | gzip > /tmp/dumptables.sql.gz
```

Could you please take a look at the above query and let me know what is the problem? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `--where` option in quotes, because backticks and `>` have special meaning to the shell.

```sh
mysqldump -u username -p password database1 table1 table3 table4 --where='`id`>=500'  | gzip > /tmp/dumptables.sql.gz
```

You also should be running this command from the `Terminal`, not `phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: thanks for your time and answer, unfortunately I'm getting the same error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u user -p password database1 table1 table3 table4 --wher' at line 1 
`

Comment: You're trying to run `mysqldump` from the `mysql>` prompt. It's a shell command, not a mysql command.

Comment: so, shall I enter it through the terminal?

Comment: Yes, that's how you access the shell on OS X.

Comment: sorry because I'm very new to programming

Comment: I use AMPPS to run MySQL and my database files are in `/Applications/AMPPS/var/database1`, so do I need to `cd` to this directory and run your command? Because now I'm getting the `-bash: table1: command not found` ... errors

Comment: That shouldn't happen if you typed the command as I showed. That error would happen if you put `table1` at the beginning of the command line.

Comment: thanks again, now the error is `-bash: mysqldump: command not found`

Comment: You need to use the full pathname to the `mysqldump` command, or add the directory that contains the `mysqldump` executable to your PATH environment variable. You need to learn the basics of using the shell in Unix.

Comment: What if I don't want the where clause to apply to the table1 for instance?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368101/mysqldump-with-multiple-tables-with-or-without-where-clause