# mysqldump with multiple tables with or without where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a set of tables in my database that I have to take a dump ( :D ) of. My problem is I want to take some data from some tables that only date back certain days and would like to keep the remaining tables in tact.

The query I came up with was something like:

```
mysqldump -h<hostname> -u<username> -p <databasename> 
<table1> <table2> <table3> 
<table4> --where 'created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)',
<table5> --where 'created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
--single-transaction --no-create-info | gzip
> $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H)-dump.sql.gz
```

The trouble with the above code is that table1, table2 and table3 will try to take the where clause of table4. I don't want that cause that would spit out an error that created field does not exist in these tables.

I tried putting comma (,) after table names as I did after where clause but it doesn't work.

At this point I'm pretty much stuck and have no more alternative expect create two different sql dump files, which I wouldn't want to do.

Comment: as goker said it wont work for different --where clauses

mysqldump -h<hostname> -u<username> -p <databasename> 
<table4> --where 'created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)',
<table5> --where 'created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)

botth table4 and table5 will be filtered by the last condition 8 day

Answer (score 47, accepted):

make two dumps or if you dont want to make two dumps then try two command

a.

```
mysqldump -h<hostname> -u<username> -p 
<databasename>  <table1> <table2> <table3>
--single-transaction --no-create-info > dumpfile.sql
```

b.

```
mysqldump -h<hostname> -u<username> -p <databasename> 
<table4> --where 'created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)',
<table5> --where 'created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
--single-transaction --no-create-info >> dumpfile.sql
```

c.

```
gzip dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: Woh! It worked. Thanks a lot buddy. 
'>>' argument appended to the dump I had already created. Awesome.

Comment: if it is linux then
mysqldump -h<hostname> -u<username> -p <databasename>  <table1>
<table2> <table3> 
--single-transaction --no-create-info; mysqldump -h<hostname> -u<username> -p <databasename> 
<table4> <table5> --where 'created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)' | gzip
> $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H)-dump.sql.gz

Comment: it does not work different _where_ conditions for each table

Comment: Do I need to take a backup of multiple tables with the same where clause is it possible ? something like this?
mysqldump -u username -p'pwd' db_name (table1 table2 table3) --where company_id=1 | gzip > backups/abc_bkp.sql.gz

Answer (score 2):

To dump multiple tables with multiple where conditions.

```
mysqldump -h <hostname> -u <username> -p'<password>' <db_name> <table_name> -where 'condition=true' --no-create-info > dumpfile.sql
```

Then, for second table, use **">>"**. It will append the previous dump file.

> --no-create-info >> dumpfile.sql

```
mysqldump -h <hostname> -u <username> -p'<password>' <db_name> <table_name_2> -where 'condition=true' --no-create-info >> dumpfile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

So the solution above won't work unless the tables have a common foreign key field.

If you look at my example below, the user_addresses, user_groups, and user_payment_methods all have the user_id field i common.  When `mysqldump` executes the where clause it will filter those tables.

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p <password> 
user_addresses user_groups user_payment_methods 
-w "user_id 
in (select id from users where email like '%@domain.com')"
--single-transaction| gzip > sqldump.sql.gz
```