# MYSQL: Selectively dump database with where clauses

Tags: mysql, database

I need to create a script to automaticlaly update my development copy of the production database to the latest data and structure/etc at will.

The problem is the production database is extremely large, but most of its size is held by about 10 tables with millions of rows I don't need.

I want to do a full database dump for all the tables, but selectively limit the number of rows taken from the very large tables so as to keep the final database size small while maintaining a reasonable sample-set to run queries against.

I have tried creating a script along the suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368101/mysqldump-with-multiple-tables-with-or-without-where-clause)

```
mysqldump -u root -p devdb smallTableNoWhereClause, bigTableWithWhereClauseAndOrderBy --where '1=1 order by id desc limit 2000'
```

Running that scirpt however gives the nonsensical error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `WH_SkuArrivals` WHERE 1 order by id desc limit 10': Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause' (1054)
```

Which makes no sense because 'id' is that table's primary key.

Is creating a dump script like this the right idea, is there a better option or will I have to create a dump script with no where cluses for all the smaller tables (about 500) and individual scripts with where and order by clauses for the bigger tables and then load each of these dumps one by one into the new database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in there

`mysqldump -u root -p devdb smallTableNoWhereClause, bigTableWithWhereClauseAndOrderBy --where="1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2000"`

you need to write it with an equalsign  `WHERE = "..."` and missing quotes

[MysqlDocs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)

Comment: I used single quotes on my first attempt, but I just tried it with double quotes as you suggested and I get the same error.

Comment: Yes sure, but on your example, there is the equal sign and the quote missing. Did you try to add the equal sign and the missing quote?

Comment: I don't see any missing quotes, I'm not sure what you're referring to. I did try your statement exactly as you wrote it but it gives an error; adding the equal sign after where makes the statement evaluate to "... Where=1 order ..." which provokes a further SQL syntax error.

Comment: Sure, there is one more thing it coud be wrong. The error could tell you that the db does not know which table.id is ment. So try it whithout id or with tablename.id

Comment: I thought about that but it just tells me it doesn't know what tablename.id is lol