# How to incrementally backup a production database

Tags: php, mysql, magento, cron

Guys I have a 10 years old store, magento 1. I have many data and I can't lost my data, but I have a problem.
There is many unused things at my store and it's becoming slow.

What I think to do:

1 - create a lifetime database called DB1 (endpoint)

2 - create a store optimized database called DB2 (I will exclude all unused information, orders etc)

3 - DB1 receives all day a incremental backup from DB2

There is a way to do the incremental backup (item 2)?

there is a way do set a period of time to exclude data from DB2?

I will have conflict problems, something like this?

**any sugestion to solve my demand?**

Comment: you canmake a mysqldump with a where clause like this for a single table see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368101/mysqldump-with-multiple-tables-with-or-without-where-clause which you could import into db1. This where work also with id fileds

Comment: Have you considered tuning your MySQL instance?  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where we have FREE downloadable Utility Scripts to improve performance, other services, contact info.

Comment: This url is foundational information for considering MySQL incremental backup strategy.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/backup-types.html   change the version from 5.6 to whatever you are using for other version details.

Comment: Could you share your current FULL backup schedule with us?